# Prove the function is continuous, exercise from Conway's "Functions of One Complex Variable I"

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity

For the first proof of Cauchy's integral formula, Conway in his book "Functions of One Complex Variable" (Chapter IV, section 5.4) uses the following claim:

> Let $G$ be an open subset of $\mathbb C$ and $f : G \to \mathbb C$ an analytic function. Then define $\varphi : G \times G \to \mathbb C$ as
>   $$
> \varphi(z,w) = \begin{cases}
> \dfrac{f(z)-f(w)}{z-w}, && z\neq w \\
>   f'(z) && z=w \end{cases}. $$
>   Then $\varphi$ is continuous on $G \times G$.

Unfortunately, he does not give a proof, leaving it as an exercise (Exercise 1).

I tried to make a direct proof by taking $|z-z_0| + |w-w_0| < \delta$ as a neighbourhood of $(z_0,w_0)$, but it lead to nowhere. I understand, that $z \mapsto \varphi(z,w)$ and $w \mapsto \varphi(z,w)$ are both holomorphic and continuous, but I do not see how one could use it.

I also saw this claim in several lecture notes but it goes unproven there either.

I would appreciate a hint, we have this problem as a homework.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: The only troublesome case is when $(z,w) \to (a,a)$  for some $a\in G.$ Here note

$$f(z) - f(w) = \int_0^1 f'(w +t(z-w))(z-w)\ dt$$

for $z,w$ in any $D(a,r)\subset G.$

---

Added the following details later: If $z,w \in D(a,r)\subset G,$ then $\varphi(z,w) = \int_0^1f'(w+t(z-w))\  dt,$ including the case where $z=w.$ Note that $|w+t(z-w) - a| \le |z-a|+|w-a|$ for $t\in [0,1].$ Thus as $(z,w) \to (a,a),$ $f'(w+t(z-w)) \to f'(a)$ uniformly on $[0,1].$ That gives the desired convergence of the integral to $f'(a),$ which is what we want.

Comment: Why integrate????

Comment: Because if you divide by $z-w$ it is easy to tell the result is continuous as desired.

Comment: The main point of this rewriting as I see is to get a clearly continuous function under the integral sign. But how then to make a point that after the integration is remains continuous in $z$ and $w$?

Comment: I added some more details.