# How do I prove that $\partial_1 \phi$ exists?

Tags: complex-analysis

Reference: [Prove the function is continuous, exercise from Conway's "Functions of One Complex Variable I"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1452848/prove-the-function-is-continuous-exercise-from-conways-functions-of-one-compl)

Let $G$ be open in $\mathbb{C}$.

Let $f:G\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be an analytic function.

Define $\phi(z,w)= [f(z)-f(w)]/(z-w)$ if $z\neq w$ and $\phi(z,z)= f'(z)$ for all $z,w\in G$.

I understand that the function $\phi$ is continuous, but how do I prove that $\partial_1 \phi$ exists?

It is obvious that this function is partial differentiable when $z_0\neq w_0$, but I have no idea how to prove it for the case $z_0=w_0$. I tried to apply mrf's argument in the above link to prove this, but I failed.

Comment: What else have you tried? Have you tried to apply l'Hospitals rule?

Comment: @skyking I think I have proven it applying continuity of the function $\Omega(z,w)=[f'(z)-f'(w)]/(z-w)$ if $z\neq w$ and $\Omega(z,z)= f''(z)$.

Comment: Use the definition of $\partial_1$. What happens if you tries to calculate $lim_{h\to0}(\phi(z+h, z)-\phi(z,z))/h$? Use the Taylor expansion of $f(z+h)$.

Comment: If you think you have proved it I think you should show your proof and ask if it's correct instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $z_0\ne w_0$ then $$g(z):=\phi(z,w_0):={f(z)-f(w_0)\over z-w_0}$$
is an analytic function in a neighborhood $U$ of $z_0$. It follows that ${\partial\phi\over\partial z}(z_0,w_0)=g'(z_0)$ exists.

If $z_0=w_0$ let $U\subset G$ be a convex neighborhood of $z_0$. For $z$, $w\in U$ one has
$$f(z)-f(w)=\int_{[w,z]}f'(\zeta)\>d\zeta=(z-w)\int_0^1 f'\bigl((1-t)w+tz\bigr)\>dt\ ,$$
which then leads to the following representation of $\phi$, valid for all $z$, $w\in U$:
$$\phi(z,w)=\int_0^1 f'\bigl((1-t)w+tz\bigr)\>dt\ .$$
Leibniz rule and the holomorphy of $f$ then guarantee that ${\partial\phi\over\partial z}(z_0,z_0)={1\over2}f''(z_0)$ exists.

Comment: That is what exactly I tried. However, to show that $\partial_1 \phi$ is continuous, do we have to use skyking's argument below? Is there a simple way to show this just like your argument showing the existence of $\partial \phi$?

Comment: Of course. The argument can be used to show  that $\phi$ is analytic in both variables.

Answer (score 1):

In fact $\phi$ is analytic. It's obviously so where $z\ne w$. Around a point $z=w$ we have for $h \ne j $ in a disc where $f(z+h)=\sum c_jh^j$ converges uniformly:

$\phi(z+h, z+k) = {f(z+h) - f(z+k)\over h-k} = {\sum c_jh^j - \sum c_jk^j\over h-l} = \sum_{j>0}c_jp_j(h,k)$

where $p_j(h,k) = {h^j-k^j\over h-k}=\sum_0^{j-1} h^{j-l-1}k^l$ is a polynomial of degree $j-1$, now we have that $p_j(h,h) = jh^{j-1}$, so for $h=k$ we have:

$\phi(z+h, z+h) = f'(z+h) = \sum jc_jh^{j-1} = \sum c_jp_j(h,h)$

so the expansion $\sum_{j>0}c_jp_j(h,k)$ holds for all $h$ and $j$ in the disc.

If you wan't to know the value of $\partial_1\phi(z,z)$ you could look it up in the Taylor expansion. It will be the coefficient for the $h$ term(s) in the polynomials $p_j(h,k)$, there's only one of them namely in $p_2(h,k) = h + k$ so the coefficient for that is $c_2$ that is $f''(z)/2!$.