# Injective complex function

Tags: complex-analysis

I need to prove the following proposition:

> *Let $\Omega$ be a open subset of $\mathbb{C}$ and $\varphi:\Omega \to \mathbb{C}$ be a holomorphic function. If $\zeta\in\Omega:\varphi'(\zeta)\ne 0$, then there exists a neighbourhood $U$ of $\zeta$ such that $\varphi$ is injective on $U$.*

**Hint:** Use that if $f:\Omega\to\mathbb{C}$ is a holomorphic function then:
$$g(z,w)=\begin{cases}
\dfrac{f(z)-f(w)}{z-w} &z\ne w\\[6px]
f'(z) & z=w
\end{cases}$$
is continuous on $\Omega\times \Omega$.

Comment: Which part have you problems with? How to prove the hint or how to prove that the proposition follows from the hint?

Comment: Here is a proof of the hint: [Prove the function is continuous, exercise from Conway's "Functions of One Complex Variable I"](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1452848/prove-the-function-is-continuous-exercise-from-conways-functions-of-one-compl).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For fixed $\zeta\in\Omega$, ‎‎
‎$$g(z,\zeta)=\begin{cases}
\dfrac{\varphi(z)-\varphi(\zeta)}{z-\zeta} &z\ne \zeta\\[6px]
\varphi'(z) & z=\zeta
\end{cases}$$‎
‎is continuous on $\Omega$. Since ‎$‎\varphi'(\zeta)\ne 0$ then there exists a neighbourhood $U$ of $\zeta$ such that ‎$‎‏\displaystyle\frac{\varphi(z)-\varphi(\zeta)}{z-\zeta}\ne 0‎$‎, so for ‎$‎z\ne\zeta$, $\varphi(z)-\varphi(\zeta)\ne 0$.‎‎

Comment: That shows only that for *fixed* $\zeta$, $\varphi$ does not take the value $\varphi(\zeta)$ in a punctured neighborhood of $\zeta$. It does not prove that $f$ is *injective* in a neighborhood of $\zeta$. – For this you have to show that $g$ is continuous as a function of *both* variables $z$ and $w$.

Comment: We get $\zeta$ on $\Omega$ arbitrary and above solution satisfied about every $\zeta$, Isn't it!

Comment: No. $\zeta$ is the (fixed) point with the property that $\varphi'(\zeta) \ne 0$. You have to show that there is a neighborhood $U$ of $\zeta$ such that $\varphi(z_1) \ne \varphi(z_2)$ for all $z_1 \ne z_2$ in $U$. It is not sufficient to show that $\varphi(z) \ne \varphi(\zeta)$ for all $z \ne \zeta$ in $U$.

Comment: If $\phi'(\zeta)\ne0$ can we say there exist a neighborhood $U(\zeta)$ that $\phi'(z)\ne0$ for $z\in U$\,?

Comment: Of course I may be wrong but I don't think that your idea works. I have added a comment to the question with a link to another thread where that part is solved correctly.